# how to manage Project in c# , ASP.NET MVC when i have a new copies and have something feature in it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have a project where i do something i have same copy from another who have do something in it later i have a thing to do currently.

so that's three copy and i am unsure that i am not confused with it. sometime i call wrong copy for finding the thing i want from them.

without using any software outside our office window any trick to manage all project or how i can manage them and make them one copy.

the same problem with some other problem come with when the same script used in two software , website who are used same script with have a small difference in both.

so i want to know how exactly all other manage them. i want to have a answer with .net plateform.

Comment: Are you looking for a version control system that integrates with Visual Studio?

Comment: struggling to understand the question.... Are you asking about source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several source control solutions that have plugins to integrate directly with Visual Studio. I would recommend looking into Subversion. Currently at my office we use Vault, but it has some short comings, especially when it comes to renaming or moving a file and then editing it prior to a check in.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/

Answer (score 1):

I recently started a small pet project. It's written in C# with ASP.NET MVC3. As it's grown, my needs for source control also has grown. Here's what I've done:

- Day one, I placed my project in a Dropbox folder. That way, I could reach my project files from all my computers (and even my iPhone).
- A few weeks later, when I first had to make some serious changes and neede a fallback, I created a Mercurial repository in my Dropbox folder and commited all my code. I've got a blogpost on that here: http://csharptutorial.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-dropbox-with-mercurial.html. Mercurial is a great versioning system, because it doesn't require a server installation and your repository is copied in full to all locations where it's checked out.
- Now, I'm looking at moving my project over to BitBucket (http://bitbucket.org/) where you also share and discuss code with others.

A good alternative to Mercurial is Git, using github.com in stead of bitbucket.org. Both have a learning curve, but they both represent modern version control tools and is well worth having a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Source control and discipline.

You need to get an approach and method for managing your source. A source control system is essential for this. I use SVN and Ankh, as does Clayton.

However, you need an approach for using this. I always have branches. You can have development branches and merge these changes into a release branch when your code has passed all the tests. This way takes a discipline and time, but you need to do this to build quality into your system.